# Handling dates and other questions in a small project

Tags: r, date

I am trying working on a small project for my class. I got a data set from  a website: http://www.cfr.org/interactives/GH_Vaccine_Map/#map

I successfully imported data by using code below

```
disease<- read.csv('Added Source information for vaccine map-3.csv')
```

My questions are:

1. How can I see some specific values? For example, I wanna list "Measles" in "Category" Column. I just want to see values column by column :)
2. How can I handle these dates? When I check its mode, it seems as numeric. How can I convert them to dates? Also, as you can see in picture, some dates are interval like "3/2010-9/2010", but some of them single date like "5/2014". What should I do with these dates to make a good visualization or something like that?

I could not add pic of table, since I just joined to website and not have enough reputation to share an image yet.

Comment: what was the first thing you did when you "started to learn R?"

Comment: I covered Louis Torgo and Jeffrey Stanton books.

Comment: Study [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can serve as a start:

```
loc <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AjivqRkNvfzudElKUDJKdlkya29wS2VUTlVFZlBoVVE&single=true&gid=0&output=csv"
dat <- read.csv(
    loc, 
    na.string=c("Sya", "unknown", "NA"), 
    colClasses=c(
        rep("character", 3), 
        rep("numeric", 2), 
        "character", 
        rep("numeric", 2),
        rep("character", 3)
    )
)
str(dat)
```

Here the `colClasses` argument explicitly defines the datatypes for each column. When the data does not fit, it raises an error. The `na.string` option specifies the entries that represent "not available" items that get a `NA` value in the `data.frame`. There may be some problems with the character encoding that I did not look into here.

To see only the "Measles" entries, you could use:

```
View(subset(dat, Category=="Measles"))
```

For working with the Date column, a first idea is to split start and optional end month into two columns:

```
start_date <- function(d) strsplit(d, "-")[[1]][[1]]
start_date <- Vectorize(start_date)

end_date <- function(d) {
    spl <- strsplit(d, "-")[[1]]
    spl[[length(spl)]]
}
end_date <- Vectorize(end_date)    

dat <- transform(dat,
    StartDate=start_date(Date),
    EndDate=end_date(Date),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

Now you can filter for entries that started in a given month, e.g.

```
str(subset(dat, StartDate=="12/2013"))
```

Comment: When I type your first code i got this mistake "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : unsupported URL scheme" Then I typed directory of file in my drive. Still, It raised an error below "Error in methods::as(data[[i]], colClasses[i]) : no method or default for coercing “character” to “3” " I going to chech other codes now.

Comment: View(subset(dat, Category=="Measles"))

This code works for me, thanks. But I have another question from this point. I wanted to plot Measles and Cases so I typed the code 

library(ggplot2)
qplot(subset(disease, Category=="Measles"),Cases,data=disease,geom="line")

and I got error which is " Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:subset(disease, Category == "Measles") "

Comment: If all fails, download the file and load it locally (I believe you did this already successfully.) Try searching questions on ggplot or pose a new question on plotting.